# How to find new features in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Does sk-learn have any method that finds new features by aggregating already existing features in dataset?
I mean something like this one: foobar=foo/bar

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to mind is [PolynomialFeatures](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures):

> if an input sample is two dimensional and of the form [a, b], the
>   degree-2 polynomial features are [1, a, b, a^2, ab, b^2]

Example:

```
>>> X = np.array([[0, 1],
                  [2, 3],
                  [4, 5]])
>>> poly = PolynomialFeatures(2)
>>> poly.fit_transform(X)
array([[ 1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  4,  5, 16, 20, 25]])
```

Comment: Hm, interesting. But I'm afraid that my an enormous dataset will cause memory-related issues with this method.

Comment: You are right, that is always a concern when you create new features automatically.